# Service Stack Filter Patterns

Tags: servicestack

When implementing custom filters I am currently using a pattern where my DTOs get both tagged with the filter attribute and also implement a custom interface that exposes some common variables I want to use in my services, for example:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    Int32 MyVariable { get; set; }
}

[MyFilter]
public class MyDto
    : IMyInterface
{
    public Int32 MyVariable { get; set; }
}

public class MyFilterAttribute 
    : Attribute
    , IHasRequestFilter 
{
    public int Priority { get { return 0; } }

    public IHasRequestFilter Copy () { return this; }

    public void RequestFilter(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        var temp = requestDto as IMyInterface;

        if( temp != null )
        {
            var x = [something from the request object...]
            temp.MyVariable = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the intended pattern?  Or is there a way to do it solely with the interface?  Is there a way to register a filter for all dtos that implement an inteface via the AppHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason to the recommendation is to inherit from [RequestFilterAttribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RequestFilterAttribute.cs) which is specifically meant for this purpose which also lets you ignore providing default implementations for **Priority** and **Copy()**.

If you do want to stick to `IHasRequestFilter` then the correct implementation for `Copy()` is:

```
public virtual IHasRequestFilter Copy()
{
    return (IHasRequestFilter)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

This ensures that only a Copy is used per request and not the same instance, important to ensure ThreadSafety for when your filters maintaining state.

Comment: Thanks mthyz, I didn't know about the RequestFilterAttribute.  I will use it.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't word it well enough, but what I really wanted to know was about the patten of having a dto that has MyFilter attribute and also implements IMyInterface.  Then inside the attribute's logic casting the dto object to IMyInterface and setting the properties of the interface.   Is this the intended pattern?  Is there a way to register a filter for all dtos that implement an given interface via the AppHost?  It seems messy having to tag a dto with an attribute and also have it implement an interface.  Is that the intended use case?

Comment: I don't know why you need the IMyInterface and don't just cast to the Request DTO directly? I'd only use an interface for handling common DTOs generically. Also this example doesn't illustrate why you'd use a Filter instead of processing it normally in the service.

Comment: I'm using an interface because MyVariable is common to many DTOs.  What do you mean by processing it normally in the service?  Do you mean having service stack automatically map the DTO?

Comment: I am using a filter because it gives me access to the HttpRequest object so that I have a chance to map custom stuff to my DTO before service stack maps the rest automatically.

Comment: You can already access `IHttpRequest` in your services with `base.Request` (when inheriting from Service).

Comment: Much clearer now, I didn't know about the existence of Request in the Service class, perhaps the docs should mention it in the section about accessing the HttpRequest, thanks!

Comment: @Pooky its in a couple places, but the wiki are community docs so if you think something is missing feel free to add it :)